# Rodapé Fixed - Z Index

Tags: css

Estou fazendo um rodapé fixo ao passo que vai dando scroll na tela.

Mas eu coloquei `z-index: -1` para ficar debaixo de todo meu conteúdo.

Quando faço isso ele anula os LINKs do rodapé.

Mas se eu coloco `z-index:0` ele fica por cima de alguns elementos da página.

E mesmo que eu coloque `z-index:1` nos elementos da página, não dá certo no meu caso, porquê os elementos são com fundo transparente por causa da imagem de background do `body`. Daí por causa disso o rodapé fica aparecendo por trás.

Como corrijo esse problema ?

Segue o código:

```css
    #all{

        margin-bottom: 120px;

    }
    ul{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }


    ul li{
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px
     }

    section{
      background: #ccc;
      padding: 20px 10px; 
      z-index: 1;
    } 

    .footer-contato{
        background: #f1f1f1;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>informações</li>
            <li>localização</li>
            <li>patrocinadores</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div id="all">
    <section class="home">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="informacoes">
        <h1>Informações</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="footer-contato">
      <h1> Footer fixed </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="local">
        <h1>Local</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="patrocinadores">
        <h1>Patrocinadores</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa tarde DeeSouza, poderia colocar um exemplo que possa ser reproduzido? No caso digo assim, podem haver outros elementos ou como foi feita a marcação html e outras regras css que afetam.

Comment: Veja esse LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/ckvda5L3/ - Eu sei usar a técnica, mas está dando problema quando tem LINK. Minha estrutura é igual a essa. Usei esse LINK pra ajudar uma usuária.

Comment: Boa tarde DeeSouza, tem como publicar a página para assim eu inspecionar os elementos?

Comment: Não tem como. Está no meu localhost.

Comment: Boa tarde, não fui eu, mas acredito que o motivo seja de não estar bem claro como ocorre os dois problemas especificados, não acho que merece negativo por isto, tem pergunta bem mais dificil de entender. Acho que é apenas melhorar. Infelizmente é ter paciência Dee.

Comment: É que não tem como reproduzir o problema. Eu faço tudo no Laravel, é Blade. Não tem como fatiar o código e colocar aqui algumas coisas. Eu fico esperando que os outros entendam a estrutura e o problema.

Comment: DeeSouza tem como pegar a página gerada no navegador e clicar Ctrl+U do teclado e analisar o código fonte (acredito que o CSS seja minificado automaticamente pelo laravel, se for o 5). Assim você poderia ter uma maior precisão. Outra ideia, não é muito boa e bem difícil de reproduzir, mas poderia postar duas fotas (de ambos problemas)?

Comment: Por que minha pergunta recebeu tantos votos negativos ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ora vamos lá ver se entendemos uma coisa:

A propriedade `z-index`, determina o "**nível de empilhamento**" de um elemento HTML. O "nível de empilhamento" - Refere-se à posição do elemento, no eixo Z (em oposição ao eixo X ou ao eixo Y). Um valor `z-index` positivo superior a > `0`, significa que o elemento estará mais próximo do topo, na ordem de empilhamento, já um valor `z-index` negativo inferior a < `0`, significará o oposto.
Esta ordem de empilhamento ocorre perpendicularmente à tela (ou janela de exibição).

[image]
[image]

## Então o que é que acontece aqui?

Ao dares um `z-index` negativo ao **footer**, ele vai ficar mais abaixo no nível de empilhamento, logo quando ele se encontra por baixo do resto dos outros elementos no nível de empilhamento, ele se tornará impossível de clicar (pois estes elementos estão a funcionar como uma camada que está por cima do footer).

## Resumindo

Ou pões o footer por baixo do conteúdo tornando-o **não-clicável/visível**, ou o pões por cima do conteúdo para o tornar **clicável**. Não existe meio termo onde podes colocar o footer por baixo do conteúdo atribuindo um `.footer-contato{z-index:-1;}` e depois trazer os links novamente para cima do conteúdo dando um `z-index` apenas para os links, pois o `z-index` agora aplicado aos elementos dentro do footer, irão respeitar à ordem do `z-index` da classe - `.footer-contato` e não à ordem de empilhamento do documento, pois esta é que é a sua `div parent`, no qual já lhe deste `.footer-contato{z-index:-1;}` previamente, ordenando-o para ficar por baixo no nível de empilhamento.

O recomendado aqui, seria trazer o footer para cima de todo o conteúdo, atribuindo-lhe um `z-index:0;`(ou superior) que irá resultar da seguinte forma:

```css
#all{

    margin-bottom: 120px;

}
ul{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}


ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px
}

section{
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 20px 10px; 
    z-index: 1;
} 

.footer-contato{
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>informações</li>
            <li>localização</li>
            <li>patrocinadores</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div id="all">
    <section class="home">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="informacoes">
        <h1>Informações</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="footer-contato">
        <h1> Footer fixed </h1>
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </section>
    <section class="local">
        <h1>Local</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="patrocinadores">
        <h1>Patrocinadores</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```